# Postgres, How to do a LEFT JOIN on JSONB array integer

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table "Photos" that references a list of persons shown in the photo.
The persons are referenced in a JSONB column named "persons" containing a json like in this format [1,2,3,4,5]

```
CREATE TABLE Photos (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT,
  persons JSONB
);

CREATE TABLE Person(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);
```

**I want to do a LEFT JOIN** but I can't figure out how. Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM photos p LEFT JOIN person ON p.persons = person.id
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest the array then you can join:

```
select ph.id, ph.name, pe.*
from photos ph
  left join jsonb_array_elements(ph.persons) as p(pid) on true
  left join person pe on pe.id = p.pid::int
```

The first left join expands all array elements to rows. A left join is required, otherwise photos with an empty `persons` array would not show up. Then you can join against the person table.

Comment: @Philiz: with a properly normalized model this would be a lot more efficient though